# Adding new actions to identify feature context menu

Tags: pyqgis, select, popup, tools, identify

How can I add new actions to identify feature context menu? I mean when selecting a feature with identify tool and right click on the selected feature, here I want to add new actions to the popup menu.

[image: this picture is showing the required]

Comment: What type of new actions are you looking to add?

Comment: I think that you can't add new actions to this context menu because it is created on the fly.

Comment: @whyzar i want to some new menu items to do some calculations on the selected feature.

Comment: @FranciscoRaga have any link confirms your thoughts? thx.

Comment: @FranciscoRaga The link not working

Comment: Update link and delete before comment. https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/gui/qgsidentifymenu.cpp#L68

Answer (score 4):

You can do that accessing the `QgsMapToolIdentify.identifyMenu()` and adding a custom action to it.

[image]

To test it, just run once the following code snippet in the QGIS Python Console. Then activate the identify map tool and... *voilà* !

```
b_action_added = False  # To avoid duplicating the action

def action_slot(layer, feature):
    """What our new action will do?"""
    QMessageBox.information(iface.mainWindow(),
                            "Feature's WKT ({}:{})".format(layer.name(), feature.id()),
                            feature.geometry().asWkt())

def add_action(tool, old_tool):
    """Add the new action to the identify menu"""
    global b_action_added
    if not b_action_added and isinstance(tool, QgsMapToolIdentify):
        b_action_added = True
        menu = tool.identifyMenu()
        my_action = QgsMapLayerAction("Show feature's WKT", 
                                      menu, 
                                      QgsMapLayerType.VectorLayer, 
                                      QgsMapLayerAction.SingleFeature)
        my_action.triggeredForFeature.connect(action_slot)
        menu.addCustomAction(my_action)

iface.mapCanvas().mapToolSet.connect(add_action)
```

---

Note that you can achieve the same result by [creating a layer action](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/create_vector_data/actions.html#basic-fa-creating-an-action) with `feature` scope:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware, there is no feature in QGIS that provide you with the ability to customize the `view feature form` as shown in your image below, when you identify a feature. The only features that allow for customization is to follow up with selecting a auto open form, which will provide a dialogue box that could be edit if needed or view able in conjunction with the identify console box.

[image]

You may want to look in QT designer in creating a custom form that may be helpful in finding a solution.

[QGIS Tips – Custom feature forms with Python logic](https://nathanw.net/2011/09/05/qgis-tips-custom-feature-forms-with-python-logic/)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this feature. 1+ becuase i don't know this feature.